# What does "get down" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In football context, what does it mean?

45+1' SAVE!

Richards **gets down** well to stop Myers' driven effort with Sass-Davies then sweeping behind to clear.

[1-0] #CreweAlex

Answer (score 2):

It means that Richards either crouches, squats or falls to his knees to stop the ball. In essence, he gets down low to take a low ball at chest height, which gives him the best chance of stopping/catching it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could mean he does his task well or efficiently. In this case, he saves the soccer shot quickly and effectively.

Comment: Interesting, why do you think that? Could you [edit] to add some more information, like examples or dictionary information that supports this?